# Shattering with sinusoids

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, learning-theory

Let $d \geq 2$ and $K$ some positive integer. Consider distinct points $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_K\in \mathbb{T}^d$ and (not necessarily distinct) $z_1, \ldots, z_K \in \{-1,1\}$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^K z_i = 0$, does there exist an eigenfunction of the Laplacian $f: \mathbb{T}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $sgn(f(\theta_i)) = z_i$ for all $i$?

Here sgn is signum function.

Inspired by this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/307363/14414)

Comment: What happens when the dimension $d = 1$?

Comment: Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114795/shattering-with-sinusoids